Table of Contents contains page number?
I used the command \addcontentsline as follows:
\chapter*{Conclusions and Perspectives}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusions and Perspectives}

However, I obtain the following result:
Conclusions and Perspectives138
The number 138 represents the page number.
How to fix this problem

Welcome to tex.sx.  Since how \addcontentsline works is defined in the document class, we need to know at least which one you are using to be able to answer sensibly.  Even better would be extending your code to a small compilable example that produces the unwanted result.  That will give potential helpers all they need to experiment.

You can use the \chapter{} command instead of \chapter*{} and then manually suppress the chapter number using \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}. In this way, the "Conclusions and Perspectives" chapter will appear in the table of contents without a page number.
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% Suppress chapter number
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

% Add unnumbered chapter to table of contents
\chapter{Conclusions and Perspectives}

% Reset chapter numbering
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

% Your content here

\end{document}

